# LNK1181: cannot open input file 'm.lib'

Tags: python, visual-c++, dependencies, cython, distutils

When trying to install a certain Python geophysical toolkit, I get this error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'm.lib'

I believe it is due to my use of the MSVC's buildtools. In their `setup.py` I found:

```
setup(…, ext_modules=[ Extension(…, […], libraries=['m'], … ])
```

What do I need to change in this `setup.py`—and related files?—to make this work. IIRC there is a library other than `m` which I am to use.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Although I can't tell with certainty the linker of gcc is looking for file libm.a if option -lm is given, while MSVC's tools are looking for m.lib which does not exist. If I find a solution I will post it.

Comment: I had same problem when I compile ffmpeg with libopus.
I took libm.a file from MinGW and it helped, but technically this file from
MinGW is dummy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Windows, the standard math functions are handled by MSVCR:

```
>>> from ctypes.util import find_library
>>> find_library('m')
'msvcr90.dll'
```

I don't have MSVC installed to test, but you just need to link against the runtime. Try removing `'m'`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while installing cvxopt.

```
 MSVC: set this variable to 1 if compiling with MSVC 14 or later
```

Setting MSVC to 1 solved this issue for me.

For more info: https://cvxopt.org/install/