# building phantomjs on windows results in LNK1181: cannot open input file 'm.lib'

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015, phantomjs

I am trying to build a custom version of phantonjs on windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015 build tools. I have added the gstreamer dev library so I can handle streaming content. When ever I run the build script I get the error:

LNK1181: cannot open input file 'm.lib'

I have viewed other posts on here and the closest one I have found is:
[lnk1181 cannot open input file m.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333898/lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-m-lib)

However the answer in there is to remove the inclusion of the 'm' library.

How can I do this as I am not sure where to look?

I have tried finding all setup.py files and nothing I can see mentions this library. I have even done a search on all python files and still nothing.
I know this is not specific to phantomjs, but I am wondering if there is a configuration file in here somewhere that can turn this include off so that I dont get these linker errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.